# Passing a variable to params with python requests.get

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently sending an api request and am using the following params:

```
params = (
    ('adminDeviceSpaceId', '1'),
    ('fields', 'special.field'),
    ('query', 'user.email_address="myemail@mymail.com"'),
)
```

requests.get works fine, i need to replace the email with a variable (passed in from another program).  When i replace the email= with

```
EMAIL_VARIABLE = 'myemail@mymail.com'
('query', 'user.email_address="(EMAIL_VARIABLE)"'),
```

it does not work, tried every permutation of removing and changing quotes.  Has to be something simple.

It is on RHEL7 so it is python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For anyone using Python 3**

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

```
f"user.email_address={EMAIL_VARIABLE}"
```

Usage :

```
>>> print(f'user.email_address={EMAIL_VARIABLE}')
user.email_address=myemail@mymail.com
```

**Python 2.7**

```
print 'user.email_address={}'.format(EMAIL_VARIABLE))
```

or

```
print 'user.email_address={0}'.format(EMAIL_VARIABLE))
```

https://pyformat.info/#simple

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.7 you can use:

```
'user.email_address="{}"'.format(EMAIL_VARIABLE)
```